# Make images copy protected?

Tags: windows, mac, dvd-burning, copy-protection

I would like to know that how can we make images/videos/files burnt onto CD/DVD copy protected ?
I want that another users should not be able to copy my pictures.

Comment: The only option is to not give them the CD/DVD.  If you can read something, you can copy it.  That's a law of nature.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your requirement?  You can include copy protection with glass master DVD, but anyone that can view a photo can copy it - with a screenshot at the simplest level.

Comment: @Paul yes screenshot is ok because screenshot quality will not be same as actual image.

Comment: A screenshot can be as good as the actual image, if you provide the actual image.  You can just 100% zoom.  If you don't mind lower res versions being copied, then only provide lower res files.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If the file is on the disk anyone can read it. Many copy protection schemes have been tried and failed - both because the protection can be circumvented and because they are a nuisance to 'honest' users.

In the specific case where the DVD is a preview or contains samples, I suggest [watermarking your images](https://www.google.com/search?q=watermarking+your+images).

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot protect the images directly if burnt onto media, you could do something alternative that will probably do something similar. There are many prebuilt solutions for Flash Slideshows that you can use to compile your photos into a Flash video/slideshow. Also, watermark the images and this would allow the recipients to view and review the photos without making it worth their while to copy them.